# Readable stream implementation for big strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I want to implement a readable stream for strings that can have a size of 1MB+, they are created by processing some files of a big size too. These strings will be sent by HTTP protocol to multiple clients and it is needed to send their content asynchronously. The question is: How should I organize the string spliting / reading and what size should I use for the chunked data? In the File System module, as I observed, it is used the size of 64KB when streaming file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [GridFS in MongoDB.](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Specification)

You can handle files in chunks in MongoDB using `GridFS`.

It is pretty straightforward.

Save with file type and download it with appropriate file type.